# How can I disable default tabs on project page in Teamcity?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I want to configure project home page in Teamcity (I'm using `TeamCity Professional 9.1.3 (build 37176)`).

There are several default tabs there which we are don't use with current project - `Investigations`, `Muted Problems` and so on. I want to completely disable them.

I am able to add new tabs via `Administration - Project Settings - Report Tabs`, but I cannot find any options to configure default tabs there. Checked also settings for root project, but there are no options there as well.

Is there any way to remove these tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to hide these tabs now. You are welcome to add a feature request [in our tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW)